# htaccess regex rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I'm trying to change this:

> /news/index.php?id=101&title=this-is-a-very-long-title

to this:

> /news/this-is-a-very-long-title/

with htaccess rewrite rule. Any idea how?

I have tried:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteRule ^.+/news/index.php?title=$1 [NC,L,R]
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://www.whathaveyoutried.com/)

Comment: @Nightfirecat:Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{SCRIPT_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^.+/news/index.php?title=$1 [NC,L,R]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is what you need:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !index\.php   [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*/([^/]+)/?   news/index.php?id=101&title=$1  [L,NC]
```

Maps silently

`http://example.com/news/this-is-a-very-long-title/` with or without trailing slash

To:

`http://example.com/news/index.php?id=101&title=this-is-a-very-long-title`

In your rule the string `id=101&` is not present in the substitution URL, so remove it from the rewrite rule if it is not needed.

For permanent and visible redirection, replace `[L,NC]` with `[R=301,L,NC]`.

Comment: thanks, but what I need is actually the reverse of that. What i want is to map _http://example.com/news/index.php?id=101&title=this-is-a-very-long-title_ to _http://example.com/news/this-is-a-very-long-title/_. I will try your solution to do the reverse.